# JPA: Using composite primary keys for map relations

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

Following an [relation mapping example](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/MapKeyColumns#Example_of_a_map_key_column_relationship_database) for Maps, I have

EMPLOYEE

```
ID  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    SALARY
1   Bob         Way         50000
2   Sarah       Smith       60000
```

PHONE

```
ID  OWNER_ID    PHONE_TYPE  AREACODE    NUMBER
1   1           home        613         792-7777
2   1           cell        613         798-6666
3   2           home        416         792-9999
4   2           fax         416         798-5555
```

Example of a map key column relationship annotation

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
  @MapKeyColumn(name="PHONE_TYPE")
  private Map<String, Phone> phones;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Phone {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
  @ManyToOne
  private Employee owner;
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to signal that OWNER_ID and PHONE_TYPE is the composite primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to signal a composite primary key, because the PHONE_TYPE is part of the Map in the `Employee` class and OWNER_id is part of the `Phone` class. Beside that, that is also not your primary key: the primary key is the id property (as you have it). What you actually need is to specify a unique key over those two columns. In order to do that, one solution would be to give up the `Map` in the Employee class and to move the `phoneType` in the `Phone` class, where you can then add the `UniqueConstraint`.

PS: Of course, if you can/want you can simply the constraint on the DB-level, without any changes on the level of the Java code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But when I move the phone_type how could I hold a reference from employee to phones, i.e. how to get all referenced entities?

Comment: As a `List<Phone>`. The small disadvantage is that you cannot retrieve quickly a phone by its type from that List, but the big advantage is that you get more flexibility when it comes to mapping and probably the search itself.